# Apache2 virtual host don't work

Tags: apache

I have problem with Virtual Host in Linux Mint. I raded many tutorials and this's don't work for me.

My file in sites-avaliable:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example
   DocumentRoot /home/john/Projects/example
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.1.1   john-notebook

127.0.0.1 example
```

When I write in browser example I see default page not example.

Comment: I crete link to sites-enabled too

Comment: have create symblink `sudo a2ensite example`

Comment: have you got any error or warning

Comment: @crack Thanks for that. My file in sites-avaliabes must have name *.conf

Comment: Not necessary that must need to *.conf
sometimes apache2 set 000defaults as the defaults virtual host. so that time you need to disite 000default